# ASP.NET PasswordRecovery Control - Always "Success" even when wrong answer supplied?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with a PasswordRecovery control that is always resetting passwords, even when the answer the user provides is incorrect.  It doesn't seem to be firing the "OnAnswerLookupError" event.  Has anyone ever run into this or have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Pretty straightforward code, I'll paste it below.  The only real customization it's got is letting the users who are locked out reset their passwords (per request from our client):

```
<%@ Page Title="Password Recovery" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="PasswordRecovery.aspx.cs" Inherits="OurApp.UI.Account.PasswordRecovery" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <h2>
        Password Recovery
    </h2>
    <p>
        Follow instructions to reset your password.
    </p>

    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="red" />

     <asp:PasswordRecovery SuccessText="Your password was successfully reset and emailed to you." 
      OnAnswerLookupError="UserLookupError" 
      OnUserLookupError="UserLookupError"
      OnVerifyingUser="UserCheck"
      QuestionFailureText="Incorrect answer. Please try again." runat="server" ID="RecoveryInput" 
      UserNameFailureText="Username not found." 
      OnSendingMail="RecoveryInput_SendingMail">

    <MailDefinition IsBodyHtml="false" BodyFileName="~/Account/email.ascx" 
           From="DoNotReply@ourdomain.com" 
           Subject="Our App - Password Reset" 
           Priority="High">
    </MailDefinition>

    <UserNameTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" DefaultButton="submit">
        <dl>
            <dd>User Name</dd>
            <dd>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Username" runat="server" AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF" />
            </dd>
            <dt></dt>
            <dd>
                <asp:Button ID="submit" 
                   CausesValidation="true" 
                   ValidationGroup="PWRecovery" 
                   runat="server"
                   CommandName="Submit" 
                   Text="Submit" />
            </dd>
            <dt></dt>
            <dd>
                <p class="Error"><asp:Literal ID="ErrorLiteral" 
                         runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </p>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        </asp:Panel>
    </UserNameTemplate>
    <QuestionTemplate>
        <asp:panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" DefaultButton="submit">
        Hello
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="personname" />,
        <p>
            You must answer your recovery question in order to have a new email sent to you.
        </p>
        <dl>
            <dt>Question:</dt>
            <dd>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Question" />
            </dd>
            <dt></dt>
            <dt>Answer:</dt>
            <dd>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Answer" AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF" />
            </dd>
            <dt></dt>
            <dd>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit" 
                  Text="Submit" CommandName="submit" />
            </dd>
            <dt></dt>
            <dd>
                <p class="Error">
                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </p>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        </asp:panel>
    </QuestionTemplate>
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" runat="server">Login</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Content>


    public partial class PasswordRecovery : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        protected void UserCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(RecoveryInput.UserName);

            if (mu == null)
            {
                UserLookupError(sender, e);
                return;
            }

            if (mu.IsLockedOut)
            {
                //UserLookupError(sender, e);
                //return;
                mu.UnlockUser();
            } 
        }

        protected void UserLookupError(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "There was a problem resetting your password.  Please contact your Administrator or Account Executive for assistance.";
        }

        protected void RecoveryInput_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(RecoveryInput.UserName);
                mu.Comment = "MustChangePassword";
                Membership.UpdateUser(mu);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utilities.ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
                lblMessage.Text = "There was a problem resetting your password.  Please contact your administrator.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:  This ended up being due to an internal implementation of the SqlMembershipProvider and failing to capture the return code of the aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword stored procedure.  It's not a problem with ASP.NET itself.  Due to the way we have to access this stored proc (think layers of an onion) -- it wasn't readily apparent to me.  This question can be closed!

Comment: Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost certainly going to be because you are using a Master Page. Put this page into its own page, without a master page, and try it again and it should work.

Comment: I had read something about Master pages causing issues with these controls as well and actually just finished trying exactly that, before I posted the question.  Unfortunately, it had the same behavior even with a totally blank page (with this markup in a form tag).  :(

Comment: @Cortright -- Try looking at [this page](http://forums.asp.net/t/1331916.aspx) to see if it can help you out. The OP on this page sounds like he had an identical problem to yours.